# How many strings of 12 lowercase letters with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Consider strings of 12 lowercase letters, such as aksdjmnuuyio. How many
strings either are a repetition of 2 strings of 6, such as aksdjmaksdjm, or
a repetition of three strings of 4, such as akszakszaksz, or read the same
forwards as backwards.

Comment: Approach via inclusion exclusion.  Do you know how to count how many there are that is a repitition of two strings of six?  Do you know how to count how many are palindromes?  What about palindromes that are also two strings of six repeated?  What is special about those?  How many different letters can appear in such a word? (consider abccbaabccba)

Comment: Hint: Think of a more simple problem. Consider strings of 2 lowercase letters, such as ab. How many strings are a repetition of 2 strings of 1 such as aa? The answer of course is 26 - one for each lowercase letter. So we have solved this problem by counting all the possible strings of 1 lowercase letter.

Comment: How many distinct letters are you choosing from?

Comment: @Joffan I was about to make a comment about counting, but then I saw "such as"! :)